# Finger extensors bodyweight exercise

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, hands

Is there any exercise for finger extensors based on bodyweight?

I'm looking for something that can be done anywhere without any special equipment. I've heard, for example, about opening hand in a bucket of rice, but I don't have a bucket of rice anywhere near, and I don't want to waste food...

Answer (score 4):

Elastic bands are commonly used for this purpose. Commercial products (e.g. photo below) will typically come in a variety of different tensions, with the idea that you progress through them as you get stronger, but you can also just use ordinary elastic bands from a stationary supply store, and increase the tension by adding more bands at the same time.

[image]